# Issue with the animation

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to add an animation effect on the images, so that when someone hover on an image then it will move in a specific angle and then come back. It worked but improperly. So, I'm looking for your help and suggestion.

The issues are:

1. For some reason any of the images move down to the other image on hover. You need to hover on each image to replicate this issue. I have tried to fix it but nothing worked.
2. On hover, the image moves linearly but as soon as I un-hover that image it comes back without taking any time. I want it to go back linearly as it works to move forward. It should work evenly. Please help.

Here is the page URL: https://aapsiindia.org/welcome/

Here is the Css code:

```
<style>

.vcard{
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:center;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 0.5%;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
}

 .card{
box-shadow: 3px 8px 8px 3px grey;
vertical-align: middle;
float: center;
text-align: center;
padding: 3%;
}

 .card:hover {
opacity: 0.5;
box-shadow: 3px, grey;
transform: rotate(3deg);
transition: linear 2s;
}

</style>
```

I shall be grateful to you!
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and put into it a piece of html

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the transition property on the card always, not just on hover.

So, put `transition: linear 2s;` in .card instead of .card:hover

Comment: Thank you for your response and for looking into this! It's really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try @keyframes for animations because they are smooth.

```
 .card.over{
    box-shadow: 3px 8px 8px 3px grey;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3%;
    animation-name: ontop;
    animation-duration:5s;
    }

   .card.out {
   animation-name: away;
   animation-duration:2s;

}
    
    @keyframes away {
        from {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        to {
            transform: rotate(10deg);
        }
    }
    @keyframes ontop {
        from {
            transform: rotate(10deg);
        }
        to {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: The animation is working fine, but when I'm hovering over second and third picture, the third and second pictures change their positions and move downwards. The third picture moves below the second one and second moves from its position as well. Please help me with this as well. Plus, as these pics move it displays a part of it on other pic, how can we fix it. I shall be grateful to you, please help me on this. Thanks!